# aws cloudformation appsync extend query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

Am I able to extend the query by using AWS cloudformation to provision Appysnc like below so that the schema can be modularized and distributed in different yml files?

```
Schema:
      Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema
      Properties:
        ApiId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        Definition: |
          extend type Query {
            you: You!
          }
          type You {
            name: String!
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type extensions aren't currently supported but the team is aware of the issue. There is currently no ETA on when this will be supported but thanks for suggesting this as it helps prioritize work!